# A question on Borel equivalence relations

Tags: descriptive-set-theory, ramsey-theory, borel-sets

Suppose that $\mathsf E$ is a countable Borel equivalence relation on the reals, and $\mathsf B$ is a finer equivalence *of order 2*, so that each $\mathsf E$-class consists of precisely two $\mathsf B$-classes.

Is there a **large** Borel set $X$ with the property that it intersects not more than one $\mathsf B$-class within each $\mathsf E$-class?

This depends on what **large** means, of course. If **large** = perfect, super-perfect, or $\mathsf E_0$-large then the answer is **yes** (but only modulo some nontrivial canonization theorems in descriptive set theory). What about **large** = positive measure or **large** = non-meager? Just interesting.

Answer (score 4):

For non-meager or positive measure the answer is no. Let $B$ be $E_0$, and let $E$ be given by $x E y$ iff $x E_0 y$ or $f(x) E_0 y$, where $f(x)$ switches all digits of $x$ from 0 to 1 and vice versa. If there were such a Borel set $X$ which was non-meager, then its $E_0$-saturation has the same property and is comeager; however, since $f$ is a homeomorphism we would have $f[X]$ comeager and disjoint from $X$. A similar argument shows no such $X$ of positive measure exists.

(I have heard this relation called the "mismatched socks").

Comment: Yes very clear thanks. My own example is $E=E_0$ and $B$ being to have a finite *even-number* symmetric difference